# Samsung's Pen applications under CyanogenMod 9

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note

Anyone run Samsung's pen based applications for their Galaxy Note running under CyanogenMod 9?  Are there any kernel driver difficulties with doing so?

Comment: It appears http://androidcommunity.com/galaxy-note-cyanogenmod-9-build-adds-s-pen-support-20120501/ points to a long XDA thread http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1627854 that gives more details, but chaotically enough that I haven't found the answer yet.